# Generative algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, supervised-learning

If I understand [slide 4](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~marco/DM825/Slides/dm825-lec7.pdf) correctly, the idea here is that in order to compute $p(y|x)$ we can use the fact that

$$p(y|x) = \frac{p(x|y)p(y)}{p(x)}.$$

Then $p(x|y)$ and $p(y)$ are calculated using our models, let's say $y$ ~ Bernoulli and $x|y$ ~ Normal (and $p(x)$ is computed using those terms).

Using our data, we estimate the parameters for our model distributions.
Then given some new point $x$, we output the $y$ for which $p(y|x)$ is largest. What I'm a little bit confused about is how we actually compute $p(X= newinput | Y = someclass)$. We know that this is normally distributed with some parameters $\mu,\sigma$ that we have already estimated, but I'm blocking on how we can actually get a number for this (the probability of a continuous random variable taking on a single value is $0$).

Comment: I have added a link.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that we have our data $X \sim f(x | \theta)$ where $X$ and $\theta$ can be vectors but for ease of typing and notation I won't otherwise indicate this. I'm going to go through the basic procedure for Bayesian inference and hopefully you will see what you should be doing or are doing wrong.

Bayes' rule tells us that
$$
p(\theta | x) = \frac{f(x|\theta)p(\theta)}{m(x)}
$$
where $p(\theta)$ is our prior (note that this is a pdf or pmf), $f(x|\theta)$ is the likelihood of the data, and $m(x)$ is the marginal probability density of the data. Note that
$$
m(x) = \int_\Theta f(x, \theta) d\theta = \int_\Theta f(x|\theta) p(\theta)d\theta.
$$
This means that we only need the likelihood of the data and the prior and in principle we can calculate the density of the posterior. It is very important to note that these are all densities here.

Once we have obtained our posterior distribution of $\theta$ given the data $x$ we can then perform inference. One common estimate of the $\theta$ that generated our data is the expected value of the posterior, i.e.
$$
\hat \theta = \int_\Theta \theta \times p(\theta|x) d\theta.
$$

We could also look at the median or mode of the posterior (in the slides you linked to, they look at the argmax of the posterior which means the mode).

Here's an example to hopefully clarify things.
Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \ iid \ Bernoulli(\theta)$. This means that 
$$
f(\vec x | \theta) = \theta ^ {\sum x_i} (1-\theta)^{n - \sum x_i}.
$$
For our prior we'll assume that $\theta \sim Beta(a, b)$, i.e. $p(\theta) \propto (\theta)^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1}$. We want to find the posterior distribution of $\theta | \vec x$ so we use Bayes rule:
$$
p(\theta | \vec x) \propto f(\vec x|\theta) p(\theta) \propto \theta ^ {\sum x_i} (1-\theta)^{n - \sum x_i} \times (\theta)^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1}
$$

$$
= \left( \theta \right)^{(\sum x_i) + a - 1} \left( 1 - \theta \right)^{n - (\sum x_i) + b - 1}
$$

which we recognize as the kernel of a $Beta(a + \sum x_i, n + b - \sum x_i)$ distribution. We were able to work purely with proportionalities rather than equalities because Bayes rule guarantees that we end up with a proper density and so if we recognize our posterior kernel we can just throw in the necessary normalizing constant at the end.

Now suppose we want a good estimate of $\theta$ for our realized data $\vec x$. Because the posterior is a Beta distribution we can simply look up the equation for its expected value and can take
$$
\hat \theta = \frac{a + \sum x_i}{a + \sum x_i + n + b - \sum x_i} = \frac{a + \sum x_i}{a + b + n}.
$$

Comment: (+1) Good explanation. The OP cannot however expect to understand Bayesian principles from a few slides and should dedicate some minimum time to read a textbook on the topic.